# Clion CMakeLists.txt not found when switching PC

Tags: cmake, clion

I'm having issues with Clion (1.0.1) and CMakeLists.txt.

I use GitHub for my projects, and I commit them from directly within the IDE. If I then checkout the project on a different computer, the IDE looks for CMakeLists.txt in the original PC's directory.

The specific error message reported by Clion is this:

```
Error: CmakeLists.txt not found in C:\Users\Chris\ClionProjects\SDLTestClion
```

However, this is a Linux machine, so there's obviously no C drive.

Here's what I've tried:

- File > Invalidate Caches/Restart
- Change Project Root (from the CMake Window; the obvious solution)
- File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > CMake

  - There are no settings or variables here that indicate the directory above.

I can't find anything else, so either I'm missing something or this is bugged in version 1.0.1 and I need to sift through project files to change the path that Clion looks for the CMakeLists.txt file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: Wrote this answer 8 years ago and didn't know what I was doing. I see it occasionally getting upvotes, so I'm updating this.

Most likely you're a new git or version control user, or just a new developer in general. The *proper* solution is to not commit CLion's project files in the first place, but since you're here, you've probably already done so. Here's how you should remedy this problem and stop it from happening in the future:

1. Close CLion. Place an empty text file named `.gitignore` in the project's root directory if you haven't already.
2. Add `.idea` as a line in the file to ignore it. Most likely this is all you need to do, though I recommend taking the time to make sure you're not committing other files you shouldn't as well (`*.iml`, `*.iws`, `*.o`, etc). See sample `.gitignore` files [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/CMake.gitignore), [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/C%2B%2B.gitignore), and [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Global/JetBrains.gitignore).
3. If this is a shared project, it's worth making sure no other IDE project files are committed as well (Eclipse, Visual Studio, etc). Visual Studio is an edge case, as sometimes you actually *want* to commit those files depending on the project. See [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore) for another sample ignore file. However, for a student project this is unlikely.
4. Run `git add .gitignore` and `git commit -m 'Updated .gitignore to exclude .idea directory`
5. Remove the already committed `.idea` directory with `git rm --cached -r ./.idea`. If you have multiple things to remove from version control, run `git rm --cached -r .`
6. Run `git add .` and `git commit -m 'Removed items added to .gitignore'`. Push your changes to your remote git repository with `git push`
7. Navigate to your project's directory in your file browser and delete the `.idea` directory.
8. Re-import the project in CLion and the `.idea` directory will be rebuilt.
9. Remember you can re-use this `.gitignore` file in any future projects. You can often just copy/paste it if it's the same language and IDE.

**Old Answer:**

Well, I found the issue. As far as I can tell, in version 1.0.1 there is no way to remedy the problem through the IDE.

Solution:

- Go to `projectDir/.idea`
- Open `misc.xml`
- Edit the field `PROJECT_DIR` to point to the directory with the project's `CMakeLists.txt`.

I think this is a bug and this field should probably be updated when choosing a new project root. A temporary solution may be to add `misc.xml` to `.gitignore` but I haven't tested this and don't know if this will cause other problems or if the IDE will automatically regenerate the file.

Comment: Why do you put those files under version control in the first place? Shouldn't CLion be able to recreate them from just the original CMakeLists.txt anyway?

Comment: Clion has an auto generated .gitignore. Theoretically, since I created the git repo in the IDE, the .gitignore should already exclude unnecessary project files, but it obviously does not.

In other words, I didn't directly put them under version control and they probably should have been excluded automatically by the IDE.